# zsh autocomplete wildcard across the network

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, wildcards

One of my favorite features of zsh is autocomplete, especially when I'm completing a filename on a networked machine.  But how to you include wildcards (like *) and have it autocomplete from the remote machine?

For instance, say I have file1, file2, and file3 residing on a server; I want to copy all those files to my local machine, so I enter

```
scp server:~/fi<tab>
```

zsh then correctly autocompletes to

```
scp server:~/file
```

but then when I try to wildcard

```
scp server:~/file*<tab>
```

all it does it beep at me (it works correctly if the file paths are local).  Is there a set of zsh options that makes this work?

Comment: Can you accept one of the answers, please, so this question doesn't stay open?

Answer (score 0):

Think setting GLOB_COMPLETE should change this.

```
setopt GLOB_COMPLETE
```

From `man zshoptions`:

> GLOB_COMPLETE
>
> When the current word has a glob pattern, do not insert all the words resulting from the expansion but generate matches as for completion and cycle through them like MENU_COMPLETE. The matches are generated as if a ‘*’ was added to the end of the word, or inserted at the cursor when COMPLETE_IN_WORD is set. This actually uses pattern matching, not globbing, so it works not only for files but for any completion, such as options, user names, etc.
>
> Note that when the pattern matcher is used, matching control (for example, case-insensitive or anchored matching) cannot be used. This limitation only applies when the current word contains a pattern; simply turning on the GLOB_COMPLETE option does not have this effect.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, you have to escape the glob character when used in the remote path in scp/ssh.

```
scp server:~/file\*<tab>
```

This is also true if you want to, say, scp over a bunch of files using a glob (rather than doing glob completion), e.g.

```
scp server:~/files/project.\* ~/localdir
```